# Arrow operator in template declaration

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a piece of source code (based on [C++ 17 The complete guide](https://www.cppstd17.com/), Chapter 14: Extended Using Declarations):

```
struct A{void foo(){}};

template<typename T>
struct SomeStruct : T
{
};

template<typename T>
SomeStruct(T)->SomeStruct<T>;

int main()
{
    SomeStruct<A> a;
    a.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand the meaning of `->` here. It doesn't look like a trailing return type.

Comment: It's a [user-defined deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides).

Comment: its a custom deduction guide for CTAD, class template argument deduction